# Setting new page size with \setlength using a command

Tags: setlength

I want to change the paper size when using article, report, and book.  Using

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{26cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{21cm}
```

By putting the parameters in style file, so that I can call `\ironpg` from within my document

```
\ironpg
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: put `\newcommand\ironpg{` before those commands and `}` after. that will do what you ask but you probably want to set textwidth and textheight as well

Comment: Are there any rules for setting  `textwidth` and `textheight` ?  Would they be dependent upon `paperwidth` and `paperheight` ?

Comment: well it's a good idea to make the text block smaller than the size of the physical paper, but latex doesn't check this. If you ask for lines 20cm long on paper 10cm wide, that's what you get, but you can't read half the text.

Comment: If I have the aforementioned paper width and height, what values would you set  `textwidth` and `textheight` ?

Comment: Changing `paperwidth` to 13cm would leave `textwidth` the same value as for the original paper size (e.g. `A4`), which might be larger than 13cm.  Correct ?

Comment: yes of course. geometry package changes a whole set of lengths in a consistent way, paper size, textblock size margins, etc, you can do it yourself but you need to set them: each `\setlength` just changes one register not any other related things.